# android highlighting an array of bitmaps one after another

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Hi :) I draw six circle images in a surface view., like this..

```
public class GameBoard extends SurfaceView implements Surface.Callback {

CircleObject circles[];

public GameBoard(Context c){
    super(c);
    circles = new CircleObject[6];

    for(int i = 0; i < circle.length; i++){
        circles[i] = new CircleObject(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight);
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder){
    // i start the GameLoop here . . 
    gameLoop.start();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas c){
    super.onDraw(c);
    gameDraw(c);
}   

public void gameDraw(Canvas c){
    // draw six circles from left to right
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
       circles[i].draw(c);
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(TouchEvent event){
    for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        if(circles[i].onTouch(event)){
            circles[i].highlight();

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

}'

my Circle object..

```
public class CircleObject{
    public CircleObject(int x, int y, int w, int h, Bitmap bmp){
        // initialize local variables here from constructors params . . 
        // set width and height of bmp here
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap b){
        myBmp = b;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(TOuchEvent event){
        // check if event.x and event.y is within 
        // this circle then return true...,
        // false if not.
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c){
        if(isHighlight){
            highlightDuration--;
            if(highlightDuration == 0){
                 // set bit map to originalbitmap
                 setBitmap(originalBitmap);
                 isHighlight = false;
                 highlightDuration = 10;
            }
        }

        c.drawBitmap(myBmp, my_X, my_Y, null);
    }

    public void highlight(){
        // store my myBmp so i can set it back from being highlighted
        originalBmp = myBmp;

        ishighlight = true;

        // highlight bitmap
        setBitmap(highlightBitmap);
    }
}
```

my Gameloop.. (runs 10 fps)

```
public class GameLoop extends Thread{
    long tickPS = 1000/10;
    public void run(){
        while(running){
            Canvas c = null;

            c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            synchronized(surfaceHolder){
                 gameBoard.onDraw(c);
            }

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

            sleepTime = tickPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                   Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } else {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

there will be six circles on the screen and when i touch one of them, the circle will highlight for a 
short period of time and will turn back to its originalBmp (which is not highlighted). so far that works :) .

now what i'm trying to achieve is that  when i touched the first circle, i want to highlight all of them, one after the other., i mean, after the first circle was done highlighting, the second will be highlighted then the third one , fourth, and so on.. like a tween animation, 
so far my plan is to create separate thread for each circle.. i have not tried it cause i'm thinking 'bout my gameLoop handling the drawing per frame for me.., hmhmhm . . .

any suggestions guys .. ?
sorry for the long post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the need for multiple threads? You could just have highlightDuration for every circle and a variable for keeping track of the lastCircleHightlighted. Suppose you touch the 4th circle, lastCircleHighlighted = 3, keep decreasing highlightDuration3. When the duration is 0, restore it and set lastCircleHighlighted to the next (=4), and so on. If only one circle can be highlighted at any given time then don't even need to create multiple highlightDuration.

Comment: that "lastCircleHighlighted" helped me a lot :)
thanks